# how to set hidden and empty cell handling using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, excel, charts, excel-interop

I am creating an excel sheet and within that sheet a chart from c# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel interface. I have several Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterLines type series and I could not find any reference how I can set "connect points for hidden or missing values". Thanks

Comment: Try recording a macro of you setting that manually, the generated VBA code will show the object model property/method used.

Comment: How can I do that from c#?

Comment: You do it within Excel - https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html

Comment: But I have to generate the Excel and diagram from the program

Answer (score 2):

Excel Interop Chart Objects [have a `DisplayBlanksAs` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.displayblanksas?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Chart_DisplayBlanksAs).

Here's what it looks like:

```
myChart1.DisplayBlanksAs = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDisplayBlanksAs.xlInterpolated;
myChart2.DisplayBlanksAs = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDisplayBlanksAs.xlNotPlotted;
myChart3.DisplayBlanksAs = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDisplayBlanksAs.xlZero;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Ralph, it worked. I was looking for a Series parameter, never thought that this is controlled for the chart. Judit

Answer (score 1):

Excel Interop Chart has a [PlotVisibleOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.plotvisibleonly?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel__Chart_PlotVisibleOnly) property, just set it to false

```
chart.PlotVisibleOnly = false;
```